# Choosing which text filters to activate

Tags: python, algorithm, filter

We are working on a small automatic categorization system in our office.

We have many filters. They are written as python functions, and they either match a file - or not.

For each file, We run all the filters. It scans the file from top to bottom, and if it matches a filter - the file will be categorized and the logfile will have the path of the file and the name of the category.

Each file must fall into only one category.

For each file, we ran all the filters and generated a big excel file which contains for each file, all the filters the apply to this file.

Name of the file | Name of filter, So for example, the file looks like:

- test.docx | Financial Report
- test.docx | Normal document
- pass.txt | Password file

and so on and so on. 
As you can see, one file can match more than one filter.

We need to work based on this file (since we don't have access to the filters themselves), and generate a list of filters so that each filter will not match more than 100 files - even if it means some of the files wont be categorized. and of course, we preffer that each filter will match only a small amount of files.

The order of the lines log file is important. In the example log file, if both the "Financial Report" and the "Normal document" filter are on, it will always be categorized as the first match - "Financial Report".

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Could you please elaborate? This looks vaguely like a [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) problem to me, but I'm not sure... When you say "generate a list of filters" what do you mean? Select some filters from the set? Combine existing filters with `AND`, `OR` and/or `NOT`? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping a count of hits against filters and for each file evaluated, mark it against the filter with the lowest hit count. This strategy would tend to spread the hits around the filters.

You could also do multiple passes, so that in the first pass, you figure out how many filters each file matches, then sort them based on filter hit count. You can then discard matches against more common filters and keep uncommon filters for those files with a high filter match count.

You should also research graph theory algorithms; you might be able to convert this problem to an analogous graph theory problem.

Having said this, you might want to examine why you are using this strategy for auto-categorisation in the first place, since 100 matches seems a bit arbitrary. Finally, I suspect that you will not find a deterministic algorithm for this task. I have a feeling it is NP-complete, or at least NP-hard.